# table design for a basket with single products and different product set

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I am not a very experienced database designer and would like make this 
table design better.

```
ID   Title          ParentID    GroupID      Price     
1    single product 0               0        12.00     // single
2    main product   0               0        44.00     // parent
3    sub product    2               0        4.00      // child 
4    product set A  0               A        49.00     // complete price (ignore part price)
5    set part A1    0               A        22.00
6    set part A2    0               A        6.00
7    set part A3    0               A        31.00
8    product set B  0               B        0         // sum price (22 + 6 + 31 = 59)
9    set part B1    0               B        22.00
10   set part B2    0               B        6.00
11   set part B3    0               B        31.00
```

So there are four different products in the basket (and count 
basket products with sql is a problem ;)). Not very straight
SQL and I need a lot of logic to handle the result.

I know that I can realise parent/child products with GroupID
but parent/child products will be displayed different in the frontend.
I need the information, is it a set or a parent/child product...

Does anyone have an idea how to realize this better?

Thank you very much & best regards

Comment: The appropriate design depends on a number of factors. The most important of which is the type of queries that the database needs to support most often. Do you frequently trace the product hierarchy? Is it 99:1 INSERT/UPDATE:READ? Should it be accessible to less technical users?

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Error_2646 product sets can contain hundrets of products ... So insert many and read the full cart
is the main focus. Maybee mysql can do this faster than a lot of php loops ;)

Comment: (On a properly indexed table,) A query is (almost) always faster than a loop. Does that help?